# Как динамически создавать объект в state?

Tags: reactjs

Вот state :

```
state = {
orderForm: {
    fname:  {
        elemType: 'input',
        elemConfig: {
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Your Name'
        }
    },
    lname: {
        elemType: 'input',
        elemConfig: {
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Your Last Name'
        }
    },
    email: {
        elemType: 'input',
        elemConfig: {
            type: 'email',
            placeholder: 'Your email'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Можно ли создать функцию с аргументами которая будет вызываться в state и передовать в неё объект, чтобы код не повторялся?

Что типа тaкого

```
state = {
    orderform: {
       lname: this.addInputParams('input', 'text', 'yourname'),
       fname: this.addInputParams('input', 'text', 'yourlastname'),
       email: this.addInputParams('input', 'email', 'email')
```

}
}

Comment: Можно. А что не выходит?

Comment: Неа. Возвращает ошибку TypeError: this.addInputParamsis not a function.
Вот пример  -  https://codepen.io/codger/pen/QWjmyvE?editors=0011

Comment: const addInputParams = (i,t,y) => {} описать выше присвоения state, и this. убрать

Comment: Я вынес функию const addInputParams = (i,t,y) => {} за класс и у меня сработало. Спасибо! А насколько такой способ правильный? Почему нельзя использовать как метод класса? Заранее спасибо !

Comment: Проблема в данном случае в том, что для this неправильно определяется область видимости; если критично оставить исходный код, нужно присвоить this в свою переменную до state = // так: myThis = this; внутри стейта используем myThis